# keyIsDown running when key isn't down?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm working on a basic first person camera controller in p5.JS, and I'm using the move function inside of an if statement (uses `keyIsDown`) and it still moves the camera when the key isn't pressed (I mean like its down for a second then no longer pressed).

I've also tried using `while ()` but that crashes it.

```js
let d;
let cam;
let x, y, z;
let img;
let floor_texture;
//place holder image    
floor_texture = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*WI5Zw1eKEKNmRX3zreeUHw.png';

function preload() {
  img = loadImage(floor_texture);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  z = 0;
  cam = createCamera();
}

function draw() {
  d = dist
  background(255);
  cam.pan(-movedX * 0.005);
  cam.tilt(movedY * 0.005);
  fill('white');
  sphere(25);
  fill('red');
  texture(img);
  translate(0, 350, 0)
  box(5000, 500, 5000)
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === 69) {
    requestPointerLock();
  }
  cam.move(x, y, z);
  if (keyIsDown(87)) {
    z -= 0.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you don't set a new `z` every time `keyIsDown(87)`, but you `cam.move` with `z` as the argument.

So something like:

```js
z = 0;
cam.move(x,y,z); //here z = 0, so it doesn't move.
z -= 0.1; 
cam.move(x,y,z); //here z = -0.1, so it moves, even if keyIsDown isn't true anymore.
```

Every time `keyIsDown(87)` is `true`, it just increases the speed at which `cam` `move`s.

If you want to set the `z` position like that, you would have to find a way to set camera position, instead of move it.

Or you could do something like:

```
draw() {
...



if (keyIsDown(87)) {
  dz = -0.1;
} else {
  dz = 0;
}

cam.move(dx,dy,dz)
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more accurate name for `x`, `y` and `z` would be `velocityX`, `velocityY` and `velocityZ`. This is because you're adding `-0.1` to `z` each frame if a button is pressed. `z` is then added to the camera's position. So in this case, we should reset `z` to `0` after the camera is moved.

```js
if (keyIsDown(87)) {
  z -= 0.1;
}
cam.move(x, y, z);
z = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are subtracting from `z` (your velocity) on every tick while key `87` (`W`) is pressed.

Currently, this value never gets reset when you release the key.

If you want the user to have a constant speed while holding down the key, pass a constant value when the key is pressed (and 0 otherwise) instead of `z` when calling `cam.move`.

If you want the user to accelerate when holding down the key (as they currently do), you'll have to add a way to return them back to a `z` of `0` speed when the key is not pressed.